# git-upload-pack not found

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone an existing github-repository (Git for Windows) to an empty folder using

```
git clone https://github.com/di98jgu/D0016E---Digitalt-projekt.git
```

but keep getting the error message:

> fatal: https://github.com/di98jgu/D0016E---Digitalt-projekt.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

The server is working fine (others are using it). Have tried adding the paths of *git-upload-pack* and *git-receive-pack* to *gitconfig*,

```
[remote "origin"] 
url = https://github.com/di98jgu/D0016E--Digital-projekt.git 
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 
uploadpack = libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack
receivepack = libexec/git-core/git-receive-pack
```

but it didn't help. Seems like a lot of people are having problems causing a similar, but not exactly the same, error message `git-upload-pack command not found`, but don't think these solutions apply to my situation.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Works for me so the problem is probably on the client side. You could try reinstalling Git.

Comment: That's possibly a typo in the URL. Have you tried using the SSH protocol?

Comment: Is your `%PATH%` correct? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1483767/6309, and https://gist.github.com/VonC/3159881#file-senv-bat-L25-L30)

Comment: this might also mean a permissions issue (you don't have write permissions on the server)

Comment: @NevikRehnel is correct, switch to SSH protocol.

Answer (score 14):

I just come across this issue right now, it is caused by permissions, please make sure that you current account has the permissions of `git pull` and `git push`，in your case , maybe you create a private repository in Github, and not add this account as `Manage Collaborators`, then the issue come.

Certainly you also should check if the remote URL is completely correct, include case insensitive, https or http.

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me when I renamed my project on Github. In my case I changed the capitalization. The fix is to edit .git/config in your project and make sure the remote URL for github reflects the updated project name.

Comment: This worked for me, resolving the same problem but on Bitbucket instead of GitHub.

Answer (score 8):

Removing the `s` from `https` solved my problem.

Comment: Hi @kornfridge, This worked for me. Today I faced the same issue I applied your solution. It worked !. Can you please tell me why is it like this ? what is the actual issue ?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the owner of a repository, for example in bitbucket, its url will change -- and trying to push or pull you will start getting this error.

In this case you will need to change the remote origin url in the local configuration file $WORKDIR/.git/config

Answer (score 2):

In case the repository is private then check if your github userid is allowed to access that repository.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error. I use the git update-server-info, but with no luck. I copied the url into browser, it's available. It turns out the git path is case insentive. I checked the github path in the browser, some characters in the parent path is capitalized. Then I tried the exact path as the page tells me, bang! It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error whenever I try to clone a repository and forget to capitalize the url correctly.

If your repository is `github.com/myrepos/Repo.git`, you need to check it out with `git clone https://github.com/myrepos/Repo.git` using `git clone https://github.com/myrepos/repo.git` (with "repo" in lower case) will cause the error you saw.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I mistakenly tried to `git clone` a repo that was actually a `Mercurial` repo. Someone else created the project and I'd never used Mercurial before.

Felt like an idiot, but I couldn't find any answers on SO that fixed it. Whoops!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when git was not installed on the remote serving machine where the git repo was otherwise correctly. Upgrading server software.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a problem on the client side. Do you still have this problem? Maybe try reinstalling git.

As far as I saw you are developing an android app and therefore most likely are using Eclipse. There is an eclipse plugin for git: 
http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos in the URL:

```
https://github.com/di98jgu/D0016E--Digital-projekt.git
```

Should be:

```
https://github.com/di98jgu/D0016E---Digitalt-projekt.git
```

See the extra hyphen `-` and `t` before and after `Digital`

Thanks for asking the question. I was having trouble cloning `gitorious` and kept typing `gitorius`, and was getting the same error as you. Some of the answers here made me look more closely at the URL, and check on the website.

```
https://gitorious.org/gitorious/ce-installer.git
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what you can do to fix this problem.

1. log in to github
2. create a repository and name it the same name as your project
3. push the project again by doing the following:

a. 1. git remote remove origin
a. 2. git remote add origin https://github.com//sample_app.git
b.  git push -u origin master
c. enter your username
d. enter your password

HOPE IT WORKS FOR YOU

Answer (score 0):

I removed the .git part, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This suddenly started happening to me as well.  In .git/config I switched my https version of the repository url to the git@github version.  To push/pull successfully I had to create an ssh key following the instructions on github (account settings -> ssh keys).

Everything works great now!

Answer (score 0):

We have got the same problem and it was due to the fact git was put in the PATH through the .bash_profile
Since .bash_profile is only sourced on interactive sessions it did not work.

We solved the problem by putting git in the PATH through the .bash.rc instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message.

Cause: I was using https to access the repo and I had changed my github.com password. OSX was using an old password from the keychain. I had to delete various github.com entries from the keychain to get it to prompt for password again when I ran git fetch.

See more here: https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the project was hosted in **Gitlab** and when I moved it to another group which caused our build pipelines to throw the mentioned error.

In order to fix the issue, I updated the credentials being used in the pipeline with one of the permitted members of the new group.

Answer (score 0):

Few steps You may follow:

- First keep a backup of your project and then close the vs code/ur
  editor then,
- Delete the (empty folder) from the project saved location, Also
  remove .git folder (if left remains).
- Then create a new repo. from the GitHub PC app and select the
  path/source of ur repo. to that folder and move all the files here.
- if everything is working fine then try to commit your code (make any
  code change) then push to the origin.
- check it will show in ur all repo.

Comment: Please, improve format for your answers.