# gh-pages -d build has failed when using npm run deploy for Github Pages

Tags: git, github, npm, github-pages

When doing `npm run deploy` after pushing my newest copy of my application to Github, I get this error stating that it cannot find git-upload-pack. I slept on it, woke up the next morning, and the `npm run deploy` worked fine without error. Not, it is back again.

Just for some background, I did clone an old repo to update it from just React to React and Redux. I have changed the homepage in the package.json, used `rm -rf .git` to remove the git file and then used `git init` to re-instate it.

Any idea why this is happening?

```
    > todo-list@0.1.1 deploy C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\code\react-redux-todo-list                     
    > gh-pages -d build                                                                               

    git-upload-pack '.': git-upload-pack: command not found                                           
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                     

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                               
    and the repository exists.                                                                        

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE                                                                          
    npm ERR! errno 1                                                                                  
    npm ERR! todo-list@0.1.1 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`                                              
    npm ERR! Exit status 1                                                                            
    npm ERR!                                                                                          
    npm ERR! Failed at the todo-list@0.1.1 deploy script.                                             
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:                                              
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-29T20_55_53_405Z-debug.log
```

- **Update 7/30/18**: For some reason, it now let me deploy. Is this engineering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there is no other configuration file (beside `package.json`) which would still reference the *old* GitHub repository URL. [Check your `git config -l`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16986447/6309).

After your `git init`, make sure to make at least one new commit, and push to the corresponding new GitHub repository.