# *war in core.excludesfile causes git add to ignore *.p12 files

Tags: git

This is so confusing. It is easier to show using the shell commands.

Note that my `~/.gitconfig` specifies `excludesfile = /home/I063510/.gitignore` in section `[core]`

check why .p12 is ignored, pipe to sed to mask my user id

```
$> git check-ignore -v check.p12 | sed -n 's,/home/[^/]*,~,p'
~/.gitignore:11:*.war   check.p12
```

comment out the line with pattern `^*.war` and verify the .p12 file is not ignored now

```
$> sed -i.orig 's,^*.war,#&,' ~/.gitignore
$> git check-ignore -v check.p12 | sed -n 's,/home/[^/]*,~,p'
$>
```

restore original file and verify .p12 is ignored

```
$> mv -f ~/.gitignore.orig ~/.gitignore
$> git check-ignore -v check.p12 | sed -n 's,/home/[^/]*,~,p'
~/.gitignore:11:*.war   check.p12
```

git version:

```
$> git --version
git version 2.17.0
```

**UPDATE**

I tried portablegit based on VonC's answer and see the same result:

```
# git check-ignore -v check.p12

# git config core.excludesfile c:/temp/.gitignore

# git check-ignore -v check.p12
c:/temp/.gitignore:1:*.war      check.p12

# git --version
git version 2.20.1.windows.1
```

**UPDATE 2**
Forgot to mention, this happens only for the pattern in `~core.excludesfile~`, not in `~core.workdir~/.gitignore`

Comment: That's definitely weird. You might download the Git source, build it for your machine, and try debugging the glob matching code.

Comment: @torek I am using cygwin git. I do not have their gcc compiler. I guess I can download it but I suspect the cygwin build may need some special attention.

Comment: Very weird.  Can't reproduce with `git version 2.13.2.556.g5116f79` on Centos 7.4.1708.

Comment: Isn't your "update 2" in contradiction with your question title?

Comment: @VonC Indeed it is. When I posted this first I had forgotten that `~/.gitignore` is not a fixed path but rather _any_ file specified in `core.excludesfile`, either using `git config` or in `~/.gitconfig`

Comment: @0x5453 I can reproduce with PortableGit version 2.13.2.windows.1 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

> I am using cygwin git

Try and use the regular [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) ([`PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.20.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.20.1-64-bit.7z.exe)), uncompress in `C:\Git`, and with a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53606336/6309) in a `CMD` session:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

Then you can type `bash` if you want to work in a bash session.
See if the issue persists then.

Comment: I see the same behavior. This happens whether I specify the path to .`gitignore` in `%WINHOME%\.gitconfig` or by using `git config core.excludesfile`, and irrespective of the actual location of the ignore file. I have updated my question with the interaction, for better formatting