# How can I let Hugo detect theme?

Tags: github, hugo

I am trying out a Hugo theme and what happened was when I used the command `hugo server`, I see the following error message.

```
Building sites … WARN 2020/07/20 14:33:07 Page.URL is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use .Permalink or .RelPermalink. If what you want is the front matter URL value, use .Params.url
ERROR 2020/07/20 14:33:07 render of "taxonomy" failed: "D:\Hugo\bin\my_conf\themes\devfest-theme-hugo\layouts\_default\baseof.html:7:3": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/list.html:7:3: executing "taxonomy/list.html" at <readFile "static/icons.svg">: error calling readFile: file "static\\icons.svg" does not exist
ERROR 2020/07/20 14:33:07 render of "home" failed: "D:\Hugo\bin\my_conf\themes\devfest-theme-hugo\layouts\_default\baseof.html:7:3": execute of template failed: template: index.html:7:3: executing "index.html" at <readFile "static/icons.svg">: error calling readFile: file "static\\icons.svg" does not exist
Built in 100 ms
Error: Error building site: failed to render pages: render of "taxonomy" failed: "D:\Hugo\bin\my_conf\themes\devfest-theme-hugo\layouts\_default\baseof.html:7:3": execute of template failed: template: taxonomy/list.html:7:3: executing "taxonomy/list.html" at <readFile "static/icons.svg">: error calling readFile: file "static\\icons.svg" does not exist
```

It seems saying that I misplaced some of the template files. I wonder if I have installed the theme correctly, or something I misunderstood?

### What I have Done

1. Installed `hugo` and confirmed it is installed.
2. Created a new site called `my-conf` (Just trying out) and the `themes` directory.
3. I've cloned the repository into my `themes` directory. I am using GitHub Desktop on Windows.
4. Added the theme information using `theme = "devfest-theme-hugo"`.
5. Used the command `hugo server`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would add the themes as a submodule, [as in the documentation](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/), and the [theme page itself](https://github.com/GDGToulouse/devfest-theme-hugo):

```sh
hugo new site my-conf
cd my-conf
mkdir themes
git submodule add https://github.com/GDGToulouse/devfest-theme-hugo.git themes/devfest-theme-hugo
```

And add it to your configuration (which you seem to have done):

```
echo 'theme = "ananke"' >> config.toml
```

Then, [regarding `readFile`](https://gohugo.io/templates/files/#use-readfile):

> To use the `readFile` function in your templates, make sure the path is relative to your Hugo project’s root directory:

> ```
> {{ readFile "/content/templates/local-file-templates" }}
> ```

In the template: [`layouts/_default/baseof.html`](https://github.com/GDGToulouse/devfest-theme-hugo/blob/1fbcda302dc578a69c635366e9ff1c7aace03786/layouts/_default/baseof.html#L7) seems to have the right path.

Yet, looking at the history of [`GDGToulouse/devfest-theme-hugo/layouts/_default/baseof.html`](https://github.com/GDGToulouse/devfest-theme-hugo/blob/master/layouts/_default/baseof.html), I see it has changed [during a commit "WIP 2020"](https://github.com/GDGToulouse/devfest-theme-hugo/commit/deb49f77e704ffe7b4cbd0dcfaf09e6442672e72).

The [version *before* that commit](https://github.com/GDGToulouse/devfest-theme-hugo/blame/75118df462abbbcb714abb38a0100d26a42347e4/layouts/_default/baseof.html) included:

```
{{ readFile "themes/devfest-theme-hugo/static/icons.svg" | safeHTML }}
```

Which, from [the discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218819/discussion-between-vonc-and-shy-john), seems to work better!

Comment: Thanks. So cloning is not the same as adding submodules right?

Comment: @SHY.John No: by cloning in a parent repo, said parent repository would not memorize *where* your nested repository (the theme) is coming from.

Comment: I am using Github Desktop, are you aware if I can add submodules from there?

Comment: @SHY.John From what I can read in https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/708, this does not seem to be fully supported. `git submodule add`, in command line, remains the safest option.

Comment: Oh, what happened is I've tried using `git` and doesn't say it's a valid command. But I suppose the terminal command `git` comes with the GitHub Desktop right?

Comment: @SHY.John No: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54679083/6309. You need Git for Windows for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54104048/6309

Comment: Thanks, once I get this done tmr I'll choose you as correct answer.

Comment: @SHY.John Can you try the same repo+git submodule add, but outside of `D:\Hugo\bin`? In `D:\myWebSiteProject`?

Comment: Oh, my website is outside of `D:\Hugo\bin`. So it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @SHY.John Does your "`D:\myWebSiteProject`" has a `.git` subfolder?

Comment: Nope, I have a `.gitmodule` file, but not a folder relating to Git.

Comment: @SHY.John That might be a problem, for executing any git command in it.

Comment: It seems that the folder exists but hidden.

Comment: @SHY.John Then can you share a screenshot of the command you type, and the resulting error message? (in "`D:\myWebSiteProject`")

Comment: Here you go. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218819/discussion-between-vonc-and-shy-john).

Comment: @SHY.John I have edited the answer to reflect the conclusion of the discussion.